# How to select an element with custom attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, automated-tests

I am trying to select this checkbox using Javascript

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cc_filter_checkbox cc_checkbox" data-specid="a1h02000000L"data-spec="BRAND" data-value="Testval">
```

the code below works but is not ideal

```
const obj = document.querySelector("#collapsea1h02000000L > ul > li:nth-child(2) > div > label > input");
```

I tried these

`const obj = $('input[data-value="Testval"]');`

```
$('input[data-value="Testval"]').click();
```

`const obj = document.evaluate("//input[contains(text(),'Testval')]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;`

but they did not work.    Any thoughts on how I can get this to work?

UPDATED CODE with data-value not hardcoded

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
                       
  if(params.has('brand')) {

     const sel = 'input[data-value="' + param + '"]';
                
     // find the element (checkbox) with the brand name
     const obj = $(sel)[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can retrieve via data-value.

```js
const item = $('input[data-value="Testval"]')[0];
console.log(item.value);
item.click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="cc_filter_checkbox cc_checkbox" data-specid="a1h02000000L"data-spec="BRAND" data-value="Testval" value="your-val">
```

Comment: That worked! I updated the code to not have the data-value hardcoded. That did not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In that case you can fetch by data-specid instead..

Comment: I'm doing this     const sel = "'input[data-value=\"" + param + "\"]'";
                          //  sel =  'input[data-value="testval"]'

               const obj = $(sel)[0];

Comment: data-specid changes from pages to page fort his checkbox, but the data-value remains the same. that's why I want to search for the data-value.

Comment: This worked   const sel = 'input[data-value="' + param + '"]';
                    
                      const obj = $(sel)[0];